# SQL Joining the table on itself while splitting a column into 2 based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
|tag|state|time               |
+-----------------------------+
|AAA|GOOD |2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-----------------------------+
|BBB|GOOD |2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-----------------------------+
|BBB|BAD  |2020/03/19 15:00:00|
+-----------------------------+
|CCC|HLTHY|2020/03/19 14:00:00|
+-----------------------------+
|AAA|BAD  |2020/03/19 13:00:00|
+-----------------------------+
|CCC|UNHLT|2020/03/19 12:00:00|
+-----------------------------+
etc...
```

I need to make a query that should show when tags' states become bad and when they go back to normal again, so the output should look like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|tag|state|startTime          |stopTime           |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|AAA|BAD  |2020/03/19 13:00:00|2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|BBB|BAD  |2020/03/19 15:00:00|2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|CCC|UNHLT|2020/03/19 12:00:00|2020/03/19 14:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
etc...
```

The query I have right now looks like this:

```
SELECT A.tag, A.state, A.startTime, B.stopTime 
FROM
    (SELECT tag, state, time as startTime 
     FROM table
     WHERE state LIKE 'BAD' or state LIKE 'UNHLT')A
JOIN
    (SELECT tag, state, time as stopTime
     FROM table
     WHERE state LIKE 'GOOD' or state like 'HLTHY')B
ON (A.tag = B.tag and A.time < B.time)
```

However, this query displays unordered results, where startTimes are completely out of order, and a lot of stopTimes repeat, like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|tag|state|startTime          |stopTime           |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|AAA|BAD  |2020/03/12 08:00:00|2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|AAA|BAD  |2020/03/12 09:00:00|2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|AAA|BAD  |2020/03/12 08:00:00|2020/03/18 14:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|BBB|BAD  |2020/03/12 11:00:00|2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
|BBB|BAD  |2020/03/13 07:00:00|2020/03/19 16:00:00|
+-------------------------------------------------+
etc...
```

What changes do I need to make to my query so its output becomes like the required one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(state) over (partition by tag order by time) as prev_state,
             min(case when state not in ('BAD', 'UNHLT') then time end) over (partition by tag order by time desc) as next_good_time
      from t
     ) t
where state in ('BAD', 'UNHLT') and
      prev_state not in ('BAD', 'UNHLT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option with row_number() and a conditional aggregation

```
Select Tag
      ,[State]   = max(case when FR=1 then [State] end)
      ,StartTime = max(case when FR=1 then [time] end)
      ,StopTime  = max(case when LR=1 then [time] end)
 From (
        Select *
             ,FR = row_number() over (partition by tag order by [time]) 
             ,LR = row_number() over (partition by tag order by [time] desc) 
 From YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Tag
```

**Returns**

```
Tag State   StartTime               StopTime
AAA BAD     2020-03-19 13:00:00.000 2020-03-19 16:00:00.000
BBB BAD     2020-03-19 15:00:00.000 2020-03-19 16:00:00.000
CCC UNHLT   2020-03-19 12:00:00.000 2020-03-19 14:00:00.000
```